# Cannot get input number from a form in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to input number in a form (laravel 5.4) but the code is not working.

I have tried different options but it is not working.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'properties.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '' , 'files' => true)) !!}
{{ Form::label('address', 'Address:') }}
{{ Form::text('address', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Street & Number')) }}

</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

{{ Form::label('price_paid', "Price Paid:") }}
{{ Form::number('fuel',null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('loan_ltv', "Loan to Value:") }}
{{ Form::input('number', 'amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('rent', "Rent Achievable:") }}
{{ Form::number('name', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('mortgage', "Mortgage Rate:") }}
{{ Form::number('name', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('management_moe', "Management and Operating Expenses:") }}
{{ Form::number('name', 'value', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::submit('Create Property Case', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;')) }}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

I have tried different options I found here but it is not working.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'address' =>'max:255|nullable',
            'price_paid' => 'integer|nullable',
            'loan_ltv' => 'integer|nullable',
            'rent' => 'integer|nullable',
            'mortgage' => 'integer|nullable',
            'management_moe' => 'integer|nullable'
            ));
```

When I submit the form, the only thing I see in the database is the street name and the street number. The rest of the rows has nulls.

I can manually input number in the database but I want to do it through the form. Can someone help me???

Answer (score 0):

> **This is the working code I use after a lot of research:**

```
            {{ Form::label('price_paid', "Price Paid:") }}
            {{ Form::number('price_paid', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('loan_ltv', "Loan to Value:") }}
            {{ Form::number('loan_ltv', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('rent', "Rent Achievable:") }}
            {{ Form::number('rent', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('mortgage', "Mortgage Rate:") }}
            {{ Form::number('mortgage', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('management_moe', "Management and Operating Expenses:") }}
            {{ Form::number('management_moe', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```